# How will be changed the number by dividing the absolute value for storing the result of changing the divider?

Tags: math

Here is a formula:

```
RESULT = (CONST + var) % MOD
```

`RESULT` - interger, >= 0

`CONST`, `var`, `MOD` - interger, > 0

Question:

How calculate `var` if:

- `MOD` will be incremented
- `MOD` will be decremented

`RESULT` и `CONST` won't be changed.

Not bruteforce.

Comment: How about solving `RESULT + MOD = CONST + var ` therefore `RESULT + MOD - CONST = var`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about arithmetic.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
RESULT = (CONST + var) % MOD
```

Let, `NEWMOD` - incremented or decremented `MOD`.

```
var = NEWMOD - (CONST - RESULT) % NEWMOD
```

#### Examples.

With original formula.

```
(25 + 15) % 16 = 8
```

- `CONST = 25`
- `var = 15`
- `MOD = 16`
- `RESULT = 8`

Incremented:

```
NEWMOD = MOD + 1 = 17

var = 17 - (25 - 8) % 17 = 17 - 0 = 17

(25 + 17) % 17 = 8
```

Decremented:

```
NEWMOD = MOD - 1 = 15

var = 15 - (25 - 8) % 15 = 15 - 2 = 13

(25 + 13) % 15 = 8
```

---

**UPD:** now about proof.

We need to substract `RESULT` from both parts.

Because that's not a division (just a remainder of the division) we can do this.

```
CONST + var >= RESULT
```

, `RESULT` just a remainder of the division

```
(25 - 8 + var) % 16 = 0 => (17 + var) % 16 = 0
```

In other words (a special case):

```
17 + var = 16 => var = 16 - 17 = -1

(25 + (-1)) % 16 = 8
```

The answer in not an only one - numbers with intervals of `NEWMOD`.

In this case: -1, 15, 31, 47 etc.